# How to set class to input when data returned from api. Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, vue.js

I have inputs with labels that rise when input has data, like materialize ( https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html ).
I use my checkInputData function to check if input has any value and set 'with-data' class. It works when user input some data to input but when i initialize the component and data returned from api it does`n works.

How can i set 'with-data' class to my input when data returned from api?

My HTML

```
<input type="text" :value="name" @input="setName($event.target.value); checkInputData($event);" />
<label class="input-label">name</label>
```

checkInputData function

```
checkInputData(event) {
    let input = event.target;
    let hasValueClass = 'with-data';

    if(input.value != '') {
        input.classList.add(hasValueClass);
    } else {
        input.classList.remove(hasValueClass);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) for 2 way bind and use it for altering class(it will ignore the `:value` property).

```
<input type="text" v-model="nameValue" :class="{'with-data' : nameValue !== ''}" @input="setName($event.target.value);" />
<label class="input-label">name</label>
```

within `data` add `nameValue`property as well.

```
data(){
   return {
      /*other values*/
      nameValue:''
   }
}
```